# Cryptic Biography

Tags: riddle, wordplay

My life is internationally famous. In fact, infamous too in a way. Many call me illogical or unreasonable. My main rival is from Greece, unfortunately, me too.  He tries to turn away from me always.I am surreptitiously in love with an English girl. But it is hard for us to stay together. People try to separate us. Amidst all these hardships, I never stop my life journey.

Who am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps I'm

> $\pi$

My life is internationally famous. In fact, infamous too in a way.

> $\pi$ is known to students of mathematics around the world.
>
>    Maybe called infamous due to claims that approximations like $ 3, \frac{22}{7}$ are actually equal to $\pi$, or
>  due to where it was discovered involving at least Egypt, Mesopotamia, Greece, China and India.

Many call me illogical or unreasonable.

> $\pi$ is an *irrational* number (not a fraction of whole numbers) - proved by [Johann Lambert](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational)  in 1761.

My main rival is from Greece, unfortunately, me too. He tries to turn away from me always.

> $\tau = 2\pi$ ( tau also a Greek letter) has been promoted as more fundamental: [The Tau Manifesto](https://tauday.com/tau-manifesto).
>
>  A rotation of $\pi$ is a half-turn of a circle, $\tau$ is a full-turn, so in rotation they are opposite directions.

I am surreptitiously in love with an English girl. But it is hard for us to stay together. People try to separate us.

> The **E**nglish girl may be **e**, and together these make **pie**, which people like to slice up and eat.

Amidst all these hardships, I never stop my life journey.

> When written as a decimal $\pi = 3.14 159 26535 8979... $ and this continues ad infinitum.

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly the answer. To add, life of pi is a internationally famous movie too :)

Comment: Oh very good -  I missed that! Your puzzle has a wonderful range of interesting clues.

Answer (score 2):

Well, It is

> inflation(monetary) and/or its effect -RECESSION

As,

> Inflation is famous/infamous internationally. Many argue about its existence.
>  Bail-out is the main enemy of recession.

It's connection with Greece to be explored.

Surreptitious love with a British girl

> Is referred to earlier Industrial Revolution ( represented by a lady,perhaps on the similar lines as that of French revolution), to which recession can be linked with.

Amidst all these hardships...

> Inflation /recession exists and continues irrespective of any steps taken

Comment: [(psst, a connection to Greece)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_government-debt_crisis)